# upload regular file to Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager

Tags: nexus3

I'm new to nexus.
using nexus 3.
I managed to created and push docker images into nexus.
Now I would like to upload simple files into nexus.

**To which repository type should I push file to?** (I managed to upload via GUI into "maven-release" repository)
**What is the command to upload file from Linux machine?**

I tried variations of this command but failed:

```
curl -v -u MyUser:ThePassword --upload-file /tmp/LIAV2/pinokyo http://NEXUSIP:8081/repository/maven-releases/aa/bb/cc
```

I also tried maven command, and failed. E.G:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=aa \
    -DartifactId=bb \
    -Dversion=cc \
    -Dpackaging=jar \
    -Dfile=foo.jar \
    -DgeneratePom=true \
    -DrepositoryId=my-repo \
    -Durl=http://NEXUSIP:8081/repository/maven-releases/
```

[This is how the file, loaded from gui, looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOO30.png)

and third question, **can I see the content of a file uploaded?**
My final goal is load a *.war file, but I'd like to know if I can see content

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution.
Writing it here, hopefully it will help some else :-)

**Q: To which repository type should I push file to?**

A: raw (hosted)

**Q: What is the command to upload file from Linux machine?**

A:
create repository called my-raw-repo of type hosted via nexus GUI

create a file

```
echo "abcd" > /tmp/LIAV2/pinokyo
```

upload file :

```
curl --fail -u myuser:PWD --upload-file /tmp/LIAV2/pinokyo 'http://NEXUSIP:8081/repository/my-raw-repo/'
```

see via nexus GUI file is in there

### verify upload

delete file

```
rm /tmp/LIAV2/pinokyo
```

download file :

```
wget --user=myuser --password=PWD "http://NEXUSIP:8081/repository/my-raw-repo/pinokyo"
```

## verify content

```
cat /tmp/LIAV2/pinokyo
```

**Q: can I see the content of a file uploaded?**

A: from nexus go the the repository to HTML view. Press on file.